# How to start docker with "node -r esm app.js"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have installed esm package and application is working fine when using "node -r esm app.js" for local server but for production server How to make it work same with the docker?

If someone could either help me with this loading the esm module it would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? A dockerfile, docker-compose or shell command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your node installation likely doesn't use globally installed modules. You need to correctly set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to point either to the global node modules or those in your app folder, it should work.

Say if you are using the official `node` docker image as a base and you are installing your stuff with `npm install -g` or `npm install && npm link`, then you need to set

```
ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

in the dockerfile.